# Can I reset Unity's coordinate system?

Tags: unity

Unity had a meltdown a while back ([compiz](https://launchpad.net/compiz)?). Anyway, since then, Unity is mistaken about the origin of its coordinate system, so that when I open a new window, I get this:

[image: Imgur]

Is there a way to reset Unity's coordinate system to avoid this behavior?

Comment: @Zzzach..., if possible, I would like to avoid something as comprehensive as that without a clear understanding of what the procedure is doing.

Comment: Resetting the unity configuration will be as if you didn't make any changes to unity through compiz (as far as I know). If you do not find a solution specific to your issue, I would reset unity then re-customize it, step by step, until the coordinate system breaks again. You will then find the plugin/setting/configuration that caused the issue.